# Notification about changes in azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Currently, I work on a task to sync files inside azure with file-storage on a custom data center. I need the way to get a notification if something changes inside Azure file storage.
 For example, for AWS I can configure notification through lambda function. Is there any similar way to do this in Azure?

Comment: Is using Azure Blob Storage instead of Azure File Storage an option?

Comment: I'm using Azure File Storage.

Comment: The task is to sync files that are inside file storage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, this feature is not there as Azure Files binding is not supported. There is an open ticket on Github regarding this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/14. It is available for Blob Storage though (that's why I asked in my comment).

For a list of available bindings, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings.